# CI is not including its PHP files properly?

Tags: codeigniter, php, error

Has anyone see then before?

```
Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (_exception_handler) to be a valid callback in /home/nginx/domains/xxx.com/ee_core/codeigniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 63
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_php() in /home/nginx/domains/xxx/ee_core/codeigniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 65
```

Since last night, all URLs on the site suddenly started returning that message. I can't access the CP, either. From looking at the code in CodeIgniter.php, it looks like the missing functions are all in Common.php, which is included at the top of the file. Any reason CI would be unable to run the included code? (Yes, I checked permissions already....)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know nothing about CI... but the first thing I'd try is to delete the Common.php file and reupload it. Perhaps it's been corrupted?

Comment: I did try that. No luck.

Comment: Have you changed anything? Any idea when/why this started happening?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a server problem. The hosting company restarted Nginx and PHP and everything went back to normal. Mysterious.....